# Invert everything on page except imges

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to invert everything on the page except for images? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/nikita_turing/jVKw6/3/

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var css='html {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);'+'-moz-filter: invert(100%);'+'-o-filter: invert(100%);'+'-ms-filter: invert(100%); }',head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],style=document.createElement('style');if(!window.counter){window.counter=1;}else{window.counter++;if(window.counter%2==0){var css='html {-webkit-filter: invert(0%); -moz-filter: invert(0%); -o-filter: invert(0%); -ms-filter: invert(0%); }'}};style.type='text/css';if(style.styleSheet){style.styleSheet.cssText=css;}else{style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));}head.appendChild(style);})();">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: You've got some non-user friendly code there Nikita.. Can you please refactor it into Javascript so it's readable?

Comment: Why not apply "filter: invert(0%);" to images?

Comment: inverting an inverted results in a positive. `html, img { filter: invert(100%); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, use the pseudo selector `:not(img)` to select all the elements except images, then set the CSS you want.

Something like

```
$(":not(img)").css({"-webkit-filter": "invert(100%)","-moz-filter": "invert(100%)","-o-filter": "invert(100%)","-ms-filter": "invert(100%)"});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are can be two different solutions. Maybe not the best.

The first, [Find all images](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp)
Then invert elements and invert images back to the first condition.

The second, using jQuery [get all img elements](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and do the same work as in the previous idea.